# logging migrations in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

When migrations are run in Laravel 10, the only logging I can see is that the migration is added to the `migrations` table. I now have a requirement to add additional logging. Some examples are:

1. Date and time that the migration was run. This may be as simple as adding a `created_at` field to the `migrations` table.
2. SQL statements that were applied to the database. I know that some of this can be achieved with `--pretend`, but it often leaves out the placeholders in the commands. For example, if I run a migration that includes `Post::where('id','<',1000)->delete()`, I'd like to see the actual SQL that was applied to the DB as well as the number of rows affected. [I'm aware that many people would call that a seed, not a migration, but it seems to be the best way to run sql commands reliably against all environments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can only think about listening to DB events

for example you may add to your `AppServiceProvider::boot()`

```php
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        DB::listen(function (QueryExecuted $query) {
            // $query->sql;
            // $query->bindings;
            // $query->time;
        });
    }
```

Here's a [list of database events](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Events.html) that you listen too

### **UPDATE:**

Listening to events in ServiceProvider was just a quick example but it's better to use Event/Listener classes, I would suggest Event  Subscriber

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Listeners;
 
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
 
class MigrationEventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Handle migration start events.
     */
    public function handleMigrationStart(string $event): void {
        \Log::info('Migration Started')
         // ....
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle migration end events.
     */
    public function handleMigrationEnd(string $event): void {
         \Log::info('Migration Ended')
         // ....
    }
 
    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events): array
    {
        return [
            Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsStarted::class => 'handleMigrationStart',
            Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded::class => 'handleMigrationEnd',
             //MoreEventListener....
        ];
    }
}
```

Then You must register your subscribe `EventServiceProivder`

```php
 protected $subscribe = [
    MigrationEventSubscriber::class,
 ];
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is that I only want to do heavy logging for migrations. This would add logging for every DB interaction.  Actually, does the AppServiceProvider even run for migrations? I ususally run `php artisan down` prior to migrations.

Comment: Yes, when you run artisan command it bootstrap the app that's mean you have access to boot methods of service provider!  [] If you want only to listen to migration event here's a list of https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#events

Comment: @mankowitz, I did update my answer for your use case  using Event Subscriber.. I think it's more readable